# Нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Становится возможным произвести затяжку качественно (,) на требуемое усилие (,) и обеспечить герметичность фланцевого соединения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы перестроила предложение таким образом:

Становится возможным произвести затяжку качественно и на требуемое усилие, обеспечив герметичность фланцевого соединения.

Здесь качество работы - это, прежде всего,  герметичность, но при этом усилие затяжки контролируется, чтобы не было перекосов, напряжений, поэтому это однородные члены.

Вряд ли можно считать, что качество - это только требуемое усилие, и поэтому обособлять оборот со значением уточнения.

Comment: Т.е. если не перестраивать предложение, то запятая нужна только одна?

Comment: Я уже думаю, что возможно такое решение: "Становится возможным произвести затяжку качественно, на требуемое усилие, и обеспечить таким образом герметичность фланцевого соединения". В этом случае качественная затяжка - это затяжка с контролем усилия, поэтому это уточнение с обособлением. Но вот сочетание "таким образом" все-таки желательно вставить.

Answer (score 0):

"На требуемое усилие" - это скорее, "количественно". "Количественно" и "качественно" в технических текстах имеют конкретный смысл и часто взаимно противопоставляются (количественные либо качественные изменения в технологическом процессе, качественно отличающийся, К. и К. аспекты задачи и т.п.), поэтому не стоит употреблять слово "качественно" в других смыслах ("хорошо", "должным образом", "в точном соответствии с требуемым или заданным значением"). Я бы так написал:

Становится возможным произвести затяжку на требуемое (или "точно заданное", если в этом смысл) усилие и (тем самым) обеспечить герметичность фланцевого соединения.